# Store file hashes and modification time?

Tags: python, database, hash, save

I'm making a script to validate all files in a given folder. When first run, it should calculate hashes for all files in a folder (and subfolders). Then, when run again, it should once again calculate hashes for files and check them against hashes generated first time. The problem is which way to save hashes first time? Just using a text file to save them doesn't seem to be a good way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the implementation, the standard [shelve module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html#module-shelve) can fit perfectly.